# Laravel Elfinder redirecting to homepage while using 'auth' middleware

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5, elfinder

I am using [https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/issues/127) and whenever i set `middleware` to `auth` in `config/elfinder.php` file , I am redirected to home page, but whene i use middleware to `NULL` , elfinder opens perfectly fine.

How can i secure the route of elfinder in laravel , so that only accessed user are allowed to open the file manager ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solution is to use `web` as another middleware in `config\elfinder.php` file.

So, the solution becomes

```
'middleware' => "['auth', 'web']",
```

From laravel 5.2 , "web" middleware has been introduced.

Comment: A little remark : It only works for me when i remove the double quotes. Like so: `'middleware' => ['auth', 'web'],`